# which driver to show videos in my tft spi display connected to my raspberry pi through python?

Tags: python, display, gpio, adafruit

I am developing a project which is like a portable video player. I have connected this 1.14" display https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-1-14-240x135-color-tft-breakout/python-usage and connected it through the GPIO pins in raspberry pi zero. can you please suggest the drivers required to use in order to play videos in my display through python? right now, in python, I have been using pillow library and stt7789 library to show images in the same folder.

Comment: There are two drivers now: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpu/drm/tiny/mi0283qt.c (Recommended) and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpu/drm/tiny/ili9341.c. There is an outdated driver inside FBTFT project: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/staging/fbtft/fb_ili9341.c (**not** recommended).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I though you are using Ilitek 9341. For your case seems only old one is available: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/staging/fbtft/fb_st7789v.c.

Comment: thanks for the response, I have found a way to play videos. firstly, I mirrored the HDMI output to my TFT display through fbcp(framebuffer copy) and then used command-line media player such mplayer and omxplayer, to play the video and CPU usage about 50%. so overall i have solved the issue.